# Do Pashtuns belong to Greek heritage?

Tags: persia, pakistan, greek, afghanistan

From some of local Pashtuns people, I have heard that they belong to Greek Origin. There explanation was, When Alexander conquered Persia (Achaemenid Empire). he left some of the soldiers here.

But I have seen a second angle to this, When Alexander came to current day Afghanistan he found lot of Greek people already living there. They were uprooted from Greek and forced to settle there by Persians and these people later made empire of Bactria. To Support

In my personal view the Pashto is very different languages spoken in this area. I can understand some to almost every words of Sindhi, Balochi, Persian, Pahari-Pothwari and Punjabi (I am Saraki) but I couldn't understand Pashto. When I searched I came to found that [Pashto contains Greek words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashto#History). That explains a lot.

And there is another theory that Pashtuns are Indo-European who migrated from central Asia like other Indo-Aryan and Kalashi people are from Greek descendants.

Which scenario is more plausible?

Comment: why vote down whats wrong in this question

Comment: I didn't vote down, but I suspect (given that Denis de Bernardy's answer links to 2 Wikipedia pages that appear to answer your question) that it may be for lack of prior research.  The [Why did my question get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote) thread on our meta site has some other possibilities.

Comment: Yes, I downvoted because the question lacks prior research. The link is a helpful addition, but I don't see where it supports a Greek connection.

Comment: All scenarios should be supported by research.

Answer (score 5):

At least two wiki pages cover your question:

- [Theories of Pashtun origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theories_of_Pashtun_origin)
- [Pashtuns, section History and origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashtuns#History_and_origins)

The first of these mentions the Greco-Bactrian origin among other legends, and concludes:

> Prior to DNA studies, it was generally acknowledged that their origins were obscure, and modern scholars suggest that a single origin of the Pashtuns is unlikely but rather are a tribal confederation.

Answer (score 4):

The historical origin of the Pashtun is a complex and answered question. Thiis idea of a link to Alexander looks like a made-up theory to me, although a distant Greek link is not impossible as one piece of the real story. See ["Theories of Pashtun origin"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theories_of_Pashtun_origin) on Wikipedia.